# How to get path to package in Eclipse (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently reading a txt file in Java, which is located in a package with the scanner object.

To receive the file location I use a quick and dirty method:

```
File currentDirectory = new File(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
String location = currentDirectory.getAbsolutePath().replace(".", "")+"\\corefiles\\src\\filereadingexample\\";
```

- Is there a better way of doing so?

I'd love to improve my code.

Greetings 
J

Comment: Yes.  Look into Resources (which use the classpath)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to really read text file from classpath in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Use a URL

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource("/path/to/text/file.txt");
```

As the path, since your text file is inside a package, use the package structure. For example, assume your file(myfile.txt) is inside

```
com.myproject.files
```

package, your path should be

```
"/com/myproject/files/myfile.txt"
```

(mind the leading slash. It's necessary)

Now you can create a File using the URL

```
new File(resource.getFile());
```

The "resource.getFile()" returns the absolute path to the file also.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Get current diretory path

```
String currentDirPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");

String ohterPackages = currentDirPath + File.separator + "filereadingexample\\fileName.txt";
```

User home directory

```
String homePath = System.getProperty("user.home");
```